# how to answer yes or no automatically in emacs

Tags: emacs, lambda, lisp, elisp

I binded function semantic-symref to key <kbd>C-c C-r</kbd> like this:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") 'semantic-symref)`

everytime I pressed <kbd>C-c C-r</kbd>, it prompted:

> Find references for xxxxx? (y or n)

How can I answer it automatically? I tryed using lambda function like this, but failed

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") (lambda() (interactive) (semantic-symref "yes")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @huitseeker is quite neat and effective.  After four years, with `flet` and `defadvice` being obsolete, I wrote the following functions to answer yes automatically.  Maybe it's useful for someone.

```
(defun my/return-t (orig-fun &rest args)
  t)
(defun my/disable-yornp (orig-fun &rest args)
  (advice-add 'yes-or-no-p :around #'my/return-t)
  (advice-add 'y-or-n-p :around #'my/return-t)
  (let ((res (apply orig-fun args)))
    (advice-remove 'yes-or-no-p #'my/return-t)
    (advice-remove 'y-or-n-p #'my/return-t)
    res))

(advice-add 'projectile-kill-buffers :around #'my/disable-yornp)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can advice semantic-symref with something like :

```
(defadvice semantic-symref (around stfu activate)
      (flet ((yes-or-no-p (&rest args) t)
             (y-or-n-p (&rest args) t))
        ad-do-it))
```

Beware that you're locally bypassing all confirmations, so you may catch further (other) questions triggered by semantic-symref itself.

Comment: isn't [flet](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Obsolete-Macros.html) considered obsolete ? should [cl-flet](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html) be used instead ?

Answer (score 2):

To run a function without prompting for feedback, you can use a macro, this has the advantages that:

- It doesn't make any global changes to the function *(as `advice` does).*
- Any errors in the code wont lead to the advice being left enabled *(although that's preventable using `condition-case`)*

```lisp
(defmacro without-yes-or-no (&rest body)
  "Override `yes-or-no-p' & `y-or-n-p',
not to prompt for input and return t."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) (lambda (&rest _) t))
             ((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p) (lambda (&rest _) t)))
    ,@body))
```

This can be bound to a key like this.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r")
  '(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (without-yes-or-no
       (semantic-symref))))
```