# flet works, but with obsolete message; cl-flet does not work

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to temporarily turn off the `yes-or-no-p` within a function that is defined elsewhere and then restore things to the way they were.  Using `flet` works, but creates a `*compile-log*` buffer telling me that it is obsolete and to use cl-flet instead.  However, cl-flet doesn't seem to work with this attempt at `defadvice` -- i.e., nothing happens and the yes-or-no-p remains active.  Any ideas on how to avoid the error message and make this work also?

```
(defun function-without-confirmation ()

(defadvice elmo-dop-queue-flush (around stfu activate)
      (flet ((yes-or-no-p (&rest args) t)
             (y-or-n-p (&rest args) t))
        ad-do-it))

. . . .


(ad-unadvise 'elmo-dop-queue-flush)

)
```

---

I cannot take credit for the answer, because that was solved by `wvxvw`, so I'll put the relevant fix underneath the original question.  The new macro is called `lawlist-flet` instad of `flet`, and the obsolete line has been commented out:

```
(defmacro lawlist-flet (bindings &rest body)
  "Make temporary overriding function definitions.
This is an analogue of a dynamically scoped `let' that operates on the function
cell of FUNCs rather than their value cell.
If you want the Common-Lisp style of `flet', you should use `cl-flet'.
The FORMs are evaluated with the specified function definitions in place,
then the definitions are undone (the FUNCs go back to their previous
definitions, or lack thereof).

\(fn ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)"
  (declare (indent 1) (debug cl-flet)
;;           (obsolete "use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'."  "24.3")
                )
  `(letf ,(mapcar
           (lambda (x)
             (if (or (and (fboundp (car x))
                          (eq (car-safe (symbol-function (car x))) 'macro))
                     (cdr (assq (car x) macroexpand-all-environment)))
                 (error "Use `labels', not `flet', to rebind macro names"))
             (let ((func `(cl-function
                           (lambda ,(cadr x)
                             (cl-block ,(car x) ,@(cddr x))))))
               (when (cl--compiling-file)
                 ;; Bug#411.  It would be nice to fix this.
                 (and (get (car x) 'byte-compile)
                      (error "Byte-compiling a redefinition of `%s' \
will not work - use `labels' instead" (symbol-name (car x))))
                 ;; FIXME This affects the rest of the file, when it
                 ;; should be restricted to the flet body.
                 (and (boundp 'byte-compile-function-environment)
                      (push (cons (car x) (eval func))
                            byte-compile-function-environment)))
               (list `(symbol-function ',(car x)) func)))
           bindings)
     ,@body))
```

And, here is the modified function that eliminates the error message relating to `flet` being obsolete.

```
(defun function-without-confirmation ()

(defadvice elmo-dop-queue-flush (around stfu activate)
      (lawlist-flet ((yes-or-no-p (&rest args) t)
             (y-or-n-p (&rest args) t))
        ad-do-it))

. . . .


(ad-unadvise 'elmo-dop-queue-flush)
```

Comment: Well, `flet` is a macro, you can look into what it expands to and just use the expanded version. Sorry, I'm a bit confused by your code, looks like there aren't enough parenthesis.

Comment: I am trying to disable `yes-or-no-p`, like in this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591043/how-to-answer-yes-or-no-automatically-in-emacs  The code works if I use `flet`, however, it has been declared obsolete.  I do see your point, however, regarding the message being generated simply because the term `flet` has been declared by the Emacs team to be obsolete.  So your theory should work be using the guts of the macro without calling it by the obsolete name.  I'll locate the macro and try it as you suggested and report back later today . . .

Comment: That worked perfectly -- thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  I've added the fix to the bottom of my initial question, because I'm not worthy of posting it as an answer -- the credit goes to `wvxvw` -- :)

Comment: Stefan's solution is technically better (if you want to stick with it for longer). `flet` is obsolete only because of the name, just like the rest of the functions in the `cl` package, but what it does should be fine. I didn't look into other differences, but would imagine that since lexical bindings were introduced, it is possible that `cl-flet` now makes use of them by default, whereas `flet` doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd recommend you do it:

```
(defvar stfu-inhibit-yonp nil)
(defadvice yes-or-no-p (around stfu activate)
  (if stfu-inhibit-yonp (setq ad-return t) ad-do-it))
(defadvice y-or-n-p (around stfu activate)
  (if stfu-inhibit-yonp (setq ad-return t) ad-do-it))

(defadvice elmo-dop-queue-flush (around stfu activate)
  (let ((stfu-inhibit-yonp t))
    ad-do-it))
```

Contrary to CL's `flet` this will make it clear (e.g. in `C-h f yes-or-no-p`) that something's going on with yes-or-no-p.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'll try it out in the next day or so and report back -- greatly appreciated !!!!