# Disable org-add-log-note on change state

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to create a function that changes a dated task to undated, removes the deadline, and refiles it -- `without` ever seeing the pop-up window for taking notes.

I've tried everything I can think of, short of hacking the source, to eliminate the `*Org Note*` window when changing the state with the following function.  I've tried all of the following:  kill-buffer; fmakunbound; remove post-command-hook; setq nil every function with org-add-log...; delete-window; org-kill-note-or-show-branches; sit-for .... before some of the previous ideas.

Can anyone think of a way to prevent the pop-up window from happening?

```
(defun someday ()
    (interactive)
        (org-todo "Someday")
        (org-priority ?D)
        (org-deadline 'remove)
        (setq org-archive-save-context-info nil)
        (setq org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/.0.data/*TODO*::* UNDATED")
        (org-archive-subtree) )
```

Comment: Which of the commands inside your function do you think is creating this popup window? I tested that function and didn't get any popup. Since I never hacked my org into disabling notes, this is probably just an option you have to turn off.

Comment: As to an Emacs Trunk developmental release as of July 1, 2013 (version 24.3.50 (9.0)), the default behavior is to display the pop-up window when calling the above-function.  I believe the cause is traceable to the function `org-todo`, which contains a line:  `;; This is a non-nil state, and we need to log it`  `(org-add-log-setup 'state org-state this 'findpos dolog)))`.  I've tried `(setq add-log-setup nil)`, but that didn't do the trick.  The pop-up window (*Org Note*), has a message of: `# Insert note for state change from "..." to "Someday". # Finish with C-c C-c, or cancel with C-c C-k.`

Comment: If I take the function `org-todo` and hack it into a function called `lawlist-org-todo`, and comment-out the lines `(when (and org-state dolog)` and `(org-add-log-setup 'state org-state this 'findpos dolog))`, and modify my `someday` function to call `lawlsit-org-todo` instead of `org-todo`, the popup window is suppressed.  But, I sure hate to hack the source and incorporate a 231 line hacked function into my `init.el` file just to solve a pop-up issue.

Comment: Oh, and yes, that was a good idea to check the default configuration to see if any other settings could be conflicting.  I tried that this morning after reading your post, and created an init.el of only my someday function, plus the org keywords and priorities (including ?D), and experienced the same result -- i.e., the popup *Org Note* window is the default behavior in the latest release of Emacs Trunk.

Comment: The behavior I was experiencing was caused by my having an `@` within the `Someday(s@)` definition of `org-todo-keywords` -- i.e, '!' (for a timestamp) or '@' (for a note with timestamp).  So, Bruce Connor was correct that the behavior I experienced was not the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping everything in your function (after the interactive call) with

```
(flet ((org-add-log-setup (a b c d e) nil))
    Your code
    ....
)
```

It locally overrides the add log function to do nothing. (I'm writing this on a cellphone, so let me know if it doesn't work=).

Comment: If you never use this log thing at all you could just override it globally with a regular `defun`, but that's a bit more risky.

Comment: That worked perfectly and I've removed my 231-line hack of `org-todo`.  `flet` is obsolete, but still works -- the default suggestion in Emacs is to use `cl-flet` instead.  One at least one completely unrelated occasion `cl-flet` didn't work (but `flet` did, just with an obsolete error message), so I previously took `flet` and copied into my init.el and hacked it into `lawlist-flet` removing the obsolete warning.  Thank you so very much for your help -- greatly appreciated -- the function is so much cleaner now without relying on that awful 231-line hack that I came up with out of desperation.

Comment: Ah! I knew I was forgetting something. True, flet was made obsolete. Just out of curiosity, in which situation did cl-flet not work for you?

Comment: Here is the thread where `Stefan` came up with an alternative solution to `cl-flet` not working, and where the `lawlist-flet` hack was invented (inspired by a comment from `wvxvw`):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303914/flet-works-but-with-obsolete-message-cl-flet-does-not-work

Comment: You were right all along from the beginning.  It turned out to be an `@` symbol within my `org-todo-keywords` definition of `"Someday(s@)"` that caused the behavior I experienced.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Haha... org can be quite obscure sometimes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem, but if not then I think the solution is to set the value of the variable org-log-done to nil. You will no longer get the *Org Note* pop-up buffer. The logging behavior of org-todo(), which you call as the first function in your routine, is governed by org-log-done.

You can keep the existing behavior but skip logging on an ad hoc basis by supplying 0 as the numeric prefix before invoking org-todo() interactively. For more on all of this, see 5.3.1 of the Org manual and the doc string of org-todo().

Comment: I though I had tried setq nil anything and everything with word log in it, but it's possible I missed one.  I'd love to try out your idea in the next couple of days and I'll report back.

Comment: The behavior I was experiencing was caused by my having an `@` within the definitions of `org-todo-keywords` -- i.e, '!' (for a timestamp) or '@' (for a note with timestamp).