# Is there a way to use y-or-n-p for confirm-kill-emacs but yes-or-no-p for save prompt?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've seen several related questions but I can't seem to stitch them together to achieve my desired result.  These are currently in my .emacs:

```
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-no-p)
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'y-or-no-p)
```

but I would like the "Save file xxxx? (y, n,...C-h)" prompt to use yes-or-no-p instead of y-or-no-p.  I would settle for everything else using yes-or-no-p if confirm-kill-emacs uses y-or-no-p, but I couldn't get that to work either.  I removed the yes-or-no-p to y-or-no-p alias and the modified buffers exist prompt uses yes-or-no-p but the save file prompt still uses y-or-no-p.  Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there's a trivial solution. `save-some-buffers` uses `map-y-or-n-p` to ask the question for each buffer, and that function doesn't simply call `y-or-n-p`, but implements the behaviour directly (using a keymap based on `query-replace-map`). There is no default `map-yes-or-no-p` function.

Comment: I would look at the source code of each function that you want to change and use an advice specifically related to that function, or alter the function itself and create a defalias for the new function?  Personally, I just use `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)` in my init.el and that is sufficient in most cases.  Here is an example of an advice:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303914/flet-works-but-with-obsolete-message-cl-flet-does-not-work

Answer (score -1):

1. The defalias thing is a bad idea, IMHO.
2. Use exactly the behavior *you* want, by providing your own functions instead of the default ones.

IOW, the functions that provide the default behavior are on *hooks* -- they are not hardwired.  You can just replace those functions (on the hooks) with your own functions that act similarly but use exactly the prompting etc. that you prefer.

Comment: could you give me an example of how i would do such a thing/do this better?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is pretty much hardwired, after all. As @phils pointed out, you would need to write a substitute command for `save-some-buffers`, which would do what you need instead of calling `map-y-or-n-p`.  You would remap the keys from `save-some-buffers` (e.g. `C-x s`) to your command. You would also write a substitute command for `save-buffers-kill-terminal`, so it called your first command, and then remap its keys (e.g. `C-x C-c`). Doable, but not as simple as I thought.

Comment: You could probably def-advice on save-buffers-kill-terminal instead